# How can I convert a string of numbers to an array or vector of integers in Rust?

Tags: arrays, string, rust, converters

I'm writing on STDIN a string of numbers (e.g `4 10 30 232312`) and I want to read that and convert to an array (or a vector) of integers, but I can't find the right way. So far I have:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let numbers = reader.read_line().unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Rust 1.5.x, a working solution is:

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut numbers)
        .ok()
        .expect("read error");

    let numbers: Vec<i32> = numbers
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.parse().expect("parse error"))
        .collect();

    for num in numbers {
        println!("{}", num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

You can do something like this:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};                   // (a)

fn main() {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let numbers: Vec<i32> = 
        reader.lock()                           // (0)
              .lines().next().unwrap().unwrap() // (1)
              .split(' ').map(|s| s.trim())     // (2)
              .filter(|s| !s.is_empty())        // (3)
              .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())      // (4)
              .collect();                       // (5)
    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}
```

First, we take a lock of the stdin which lets you work with stdin as a buffered reader. By default, stdin in Rust is unbuffered; you need to call the `lock()` method to obtain a buffered version of it, but this buffered version is the only one for all threads in your program, hence the access to it should be synchronized.

Next, we read the next line (1); I'm using the `lines()` iterator whose `next()` method returns `Option<io::Result<String>>`, therefore to obtain just `String` you need to `unwrap()` twice.

Then we split it by spaces and trim resulting chunks from extra whitespace (2), remove empty chunks which were left after trimming (3), convert strings to `i32`s (4) and collect the result to a vector (5).

We also need to import `std::io::BufRead` trait (a) in order to use the `lines()` method.

If you know in advance that your input won't contain more than one space between numbers, you can omit step (3) and move the `trim()` call from (2) to (1):

```
let numbers: Vec<i32> = 
    reader.lock()
          .lines().next().unwrap().unwrap()
          .trim().split(' ')
          .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
          .collect();
```

Rust also provides a method to split a string into a sequence of whitespace-separated words, called [`split_whitespace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace):

```
let numbers: Vec<i32> =
    reader.read_line().unwrap().as_slice()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
        .collect()
```

`split_whitespace()` is in fact just a combination of `split()` and `filter()`, just like in my original example. It uses a `split()` function argument which [checks for different kinds of whitespace, not only space characters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_whitespace).

Comment: There is also a way to use regular expressions to split by arbitrary whitespaces. It probably would give terser code, but it requires using non-standard crates (although it is included into the distribution). The example [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/enum.Regex.html#method.split) is almost what you want.

Comment: You can also just use [`.words()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/str/trait.UnicodeStrSlice.html#tymethod.words) (slightly more general than just spaces, though).

Comment: Yes, somehow I missed it. It still is a combination of `split()` and `filter()`, as it follows from the type :)

Comment: @VladimirMatveev what would the be the best way to achieve this in today's Rust version? I've been trying to get the pieces together online but seems that the information available is not up to date. Thank you :)

Comment: @DavidDias, I've updated the answer. It doesn't differ much from the old version though; the only thing that has changed is the way to read a line from stdin and the fact that `words()` is now called `split_whitespace()`. And there is no `int` now, of course.

Comment: Using Rust 1.5.0, I'm unable to use that solution since now read_line expects a buffer to save the read line. Passing a buffer, says "as_slice" is not available for "collections::string::String". However, removing .unwrap() and .as_slice() makes it work :)

Thank you :)

Comment: @DavidDias, in the latest version of this answer there is no `read_line()`; I suggest using `lines().next()` instead.

Comment: If you write `filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok())` then it will skip failed parses.

Answer (score 9):

Safer version. This one skips failed parses so that failed unwrap doesn't panic.
Use `read_line` for reading single line.

```
let mut buf = String::new();

// use read_line for reading single line 
std::io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buf).expect("");

// this one skips failed parses so that failed unwrap doesn't panic
let v: Vec<i32> = buf
    .split_whitespace() // split string into words by whitespace
    .filter_map(|w| w.parse().ok()) // calling ok() turns Result to Option so that filter_map can discard None values
    .collect(); // collect items into Vector. This determined by type annotation.
```

You can even read Vector of Vectors like this.

```
let stdin = io::stdin();
let locked = stdin.lock();
let vv: Vec<Vec<i32>> = locked.lines()
    .filter_map(
        |l| l.ok().map(
            |s| s.split_whitespace()
                 .filter_map(|word| word.parse().ok())
                 .collect()))
    .collect();
```

Above one works for inputs like

```
2 424 -42 124
42 242 23 22 241
24 12 3 232 445
```

then turns them it into

```
[[2, 424, -42, 124],
[42, 242, 23, 22, 241],
[24, 12, 3, 232, 445]]
```

`filter_map` accepts a closure that returns `Option<T>` and filters out all `None`s.

`ok()` turns `Result<R,E>` to `Option<R>` so that errors can be filtered in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Safer version from `Dulguun Otgon` just skips all the errors.
In case when you want to don't skip errors please consider usage of next one method.

```rust
fn parse_to_vec<'a, T, It>(it: It) -> Result<Vec<T>, <T as FromStr>::Err>
where
    T: FromStr,
    It: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
{
    it.map(|v| v.parse::<T>()).fold(Ok(Vec::new()), |vals, v| {
        vals.and_then(|mut vals| {
            v.and_then(|v| { 
                vals.push(v);
                Ok(vals)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

while using it you can follow usual panicking way with `expect`

```rust
let numbers = parse_to_vec::<i32, _>(data_str.trim().split(" "))
    .expect("can't parse data");
```

or more smarter way with converting to Result

```rust
let numbers = parse_to_vec::<i32, _>(data_str.trim().split(" "))
    .map_err(|e| format!("can't parse data: {:?}", e))?;
```